# HTML conditional coding using awk function

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to change the background color of the excel depending on the range of values. If it is greater than 75, I want those rows to be in red color. If it is between 70-75, I want to be in yellow color and if it is less than 70, I want to be in green color. How should I modify my code??

```
echo "Hostname,Value" > Diskspace_$date_stamp.csv

if [ Value -gt 75 ]
then
cat Diskspace.csv| awk '{printf $1","$2"\n"}' >> Diskspace_$date_stamp.csv
elif [ Value -gt 70 ]
then
cat Diskspace.csv| awk '{printf $1","$2"\n"}' >> Diskspace_$date_stamp.csv
else
cat Diskspace.csv| awk '{printf $1","$2"\n"}' >> Diskspace_$date_stamp.csv
fi
```

Comment: CSV is a **plain text file format**. You can do nothing here to get anything colored. You could use conditional formatting in Excel to get it colored, but a CSV cannot help you there.

Comment: how can I apply conditional formatting in excel?? Can you share me the code snippet with reference to the code above so that for the cells with value greater than 65 are red in colour??

Comment: Click on "Conditional Formatting" in your Excel Toolbar after selecting the column you want to format and select the type of format you want to apply. There are hundreds of tutorials on YouTube and even more on google - and the same number of possibilities. Just play around a little...